# How to force google sign in to get new serverAuthCode after one has been claimed?

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

I'm using https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin to get OAuth2 into my application. From this, i'm requesting a server token for "offline" access.

In testing this, I didn't have my server fully put together to save access tokens/refresh tokens etc. The second time of trying to claim the token I (of course) got an error saying the serverAuthCode was already claimed. Now when I re-authorize google sign-in it does not return a serverAuthCode.

**Is there a way to force google to give a new serverAuthCode?**

**Could it be that the google sign-in library i'm using just isn't requesting/returning it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this was the library caching my user data. I simply revoked my app in the [google connected apps management console](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) and called the `.signOut()` method of my lib which seemed to fix it.